# Perform a module structure on mysql and join with MVC3

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a module structure on a MySql database that works like this on my MVC view:

```
Folder1 (id_folder)
   |----> Module1 (id_module)
   |----> Module2 
   |----> Module3 (this is disabled)
             |----> Module4 (child of Module3)
   |----> Module5

Folder2
   |----> Module2
```

This structure is for my users on the website and each user has different modules depending on his permissions (but this is another stuff).
In my MySQL database i think a this structure:

```
folder
  |- id_folder
  |- display_name

module
  |- id_module
  |- display_name
  |- isDisabled

module_rel
  |- id_module_parent (fk to id_module)
  |- id_module_child (fk to id_module)

module_folder
  |- id_module (fk to id_module)
  |- id_folder (fk to folder table)
```

I have two questions about my problem:
- It's correct this database structure?
- This is the principal question that i have.. the modules, are links to different sections of my webpage, so how do i associate the module with the controller/action method? It's a good practice to put in the module table the action and the controller? i think not.. so, what are the options that i could have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the struct that you propose can be accepted but what I do in this kind of cases is a reletionship with the same table

```
folder
  |- id_folder
  |- display_name

module
  |- id_module
  |- display_name
  |- isDisabled
  |- id_module_parent (fk to id_module)


module_folder
  |- id_module (fk to id_module)
  |- id_folder (fk to folder table)
```

in this way I found more easy iterate each module with her childs

now, with the controller and action, I guess you should have some controller for your modules so you can render a action link to the controller "Module" and action "show" or something like that and send the module id as parameter, and if you need, the folder id too, so you can do what you want in base of the user, module and folder combination